# Setting the page title for a category page

Tags: templating, categories, category, titles

I am trying to get the page title of the categories page. Currently it shows as: `category-name`, but I would like to have it set to `Category Name` to match the `category.title`.
My `categories/index.html` looks like this:

```
{% set title = category %}

{% block content %}

    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}

    {% for entry in entries %}

        -- Code Here --

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would need to know how you render your title. Otherwise it would just be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% if title is defined %}{{ title }} {% endif %}{{ siteName }}</title>
</head>
```

and in your `category` template

```
{% set title = 'Category ' ~ category.title %}
```